# Which one is my ip address in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, ip, ifconfig

I am new in ubuntu. Which one of following is my ip address ?

This is result of "ifconfig" on terminal

[image]
This is result of "ip a" on terminal

[image]

Comment: All IP addresses are "yours". And 14.04 is EoL and off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a single IP address, for your whole pc/laptop
Every NIC card has a unique IP address,so it will depend on how many NIC cards you have

But, if want to check your public ip (the IP address websites are using to recognize you) type the following into terminal:

```
curl ifconfig.me
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

The string of numbers following inet in the output of ifconfig is are ipv4 addresses. The string of numbers and letters following inet6 is your ip6 adresses.

So example in connection `virbr0` your IP address would be `192.168.122.1` Each connection listed has its own IP address.

The image below shows an example of where the IP address is located for each of your network connections.

[image: The output of ifconfig in terminal with the IP address boxed*]

Credit for the photo goes to [Wikihow](https://www.wikihow.com/Check-the-IP-Address-in-Linux).

Also, please **don't** **post** **pictures** **of** your **terminal**, rather include the output as code in your answer or if the output is long include a link to [Pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You have several network interfaces (for example your computer might have several network adapters). Each one is assigned with its own IP address.